How to show one figure in loop in Python?
I want to show a figure that is calculated in a loop, let say with 5 iterations.
This is the code that I wrote
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0,1,100)
y = np.linspace(0,1,100)
xx,yy = np.meshgrid(x,y)

for n in range(5):
  a = np.sin(xx-2*n)
  plt.imshow(a,interpolation='bilinear')
  plt.show()

With this code, I got 5 figures. How to make it runs in one figure for each iteration? I used google collab, is it possible to make the result (figure) opened in new window (undocked) like in matlab?

Maybe someone who knows Jupyter notebooks better has a different answer, but Jupyter notebooks are not the right thing to use for something like this. Your best option would be to use the proper matplotlib machinery for making an animation: https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/animations/animations.html.

matplotlib has some animation classes for this:  https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/animations/animations.html

I walk through some animation options for Jupyter, which Colab is a custom version of, here. I don't know what Jupyter versions there stuff corresponds to though because that is the first step since special set up is needed depending on versions. The text on that page directs you to options.

You can simulate an animation by using a display/clear_output from ipython (used by Colab):
import time

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from IPython.display import clear_output, display

x = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
y = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y)

# you could initialize a subplots or whatever here..

for n in range(5):
    a = np.sin(xx - 2 * n)
    plt.imshow(a, interpolation="bilinear")
    # this one is optional (to verbose my output)
    plt.gca().set_title(f"Plot n°{n+1}", fontweight="bold")
    # added these three lines
    display(plt.gcf())
    clear_output(wait=True)
    time.sleep(0.5)

plt.show();

NB: This works in any IPython environment (e.g., Jupyter, Colab, ..).


This code works well, thank you. Do you have any idea how to pause the animation, let say at n=3?

You can add if n == 3: input() as a last line inside the loop and press Enter to resume.
